# List all unique extensions for files contained in a directory

Tags: unix

I would like to see all the unique extension of files contained in a certain directory. What is the command to do that in bash?

One could use `find . -type f` to get all the files in the current directory, then strip the extension, and pipe it to `uniq`. What's the easiest way to strip the extension?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this:

```
find . -type f | sed -rn 's|.*/[^/]+\.([^/.]+)$|\1|p' | sort -u
```

It outputs nothing for:

- Files with no extension
- Files with names that end in a dot
- Hidden files

It also might be useful to pipe it to `sort | uniq -c`.

Comment: Doesn't work with the default sed on my Mac. I get `sed: illegal option -- r`

Comment: @celil: Use `-E` instead of `-r` on OS X.

Answer (score 4):

A quick and easy to remember way to strip the extension is to asume all filenames have the format "name.ext" then use:

```
 ls -1 | cut -d"." -f2- | sort | uniq -c
```

this gives a count of how many unique extensions there are, for example:

```
   1 sh  
   3 txt  
   4 txt.Z  
  17 dat  
  72 dat.gz
```

Comment: `-1` is not required. According to the manual for `ls`: " ... This is the default when output is not to a terminal."

Comment: In general cases, yes. However will return undesired results if the filename has more than one `.`. For example: `python_dateutil-2.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl`. Could be modified (by the user; albeit inefficiently) to use [this `rev` trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22727211/6340496).

Answer (score 3):

```
find . -type f | sed -E 's/.+[\./]([^/\.]+)/\1/' | sort -u
```

Works on OS X, except for files without extension. My downloads folder:

```
DS_Store
dmg
exe
localized
msi
nib
plist
pmproj
rar
tgz
txt
webloc
zip
```

You might need `sed -r` instead?

---

Minor issue: Files without extensions print their name. Hidden files (such as `.DS_Store`) print their name without leading `.`.

Comment: I'd recommend `sort -u` instead of `sort | uniq`. Less forking and resource usage.

Comment: Thanks @John. Tried to keep within celil's "framework", so I didn't think of it.

Comment: It's not necessary to escape a dot inside `[]`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's yet another solution that does not get confused by file names containing embedded newlines and uses `sort -uz` to correctly sort file extensions that may have embedded newlines as well:

```
# [^.]: exclude dotfiles
find . -type f -name "[^.]*.*" -exec bash -c '
   printf "%s\000" "${@##*.}" # get the extensions and nul-terminate each of them
' argv0 '{}' + |
sort -uz | 
tr '\0' '\n' | 
nl
```

Answer (score 3):

see, that's why I like awk:

```
find . -type f | awk -F "." '{ print $(NF) }' | sort -u
```

Comment: This is good, as it prints the **last** field - which is useful in cases such as `python_dateutil-2.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl`.